# AWS Elastic Beanstalk deployment - An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy]... permission denied

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm on Windows 10.

I created and git initialized a simple flask app that contains:

- .git
- .platform/hooks/postdeploy/01_runsomething.sh (contains "#!/bin/sh python print_helloworld.py")
- .ebignore (ignores "venv")
- venv
- application.py
- print_helloworld.py (independent Python file, contains "print('hello world')")
- requirements.txt

---

Flask app runs fine on my personal computer.
I'm trying to upload it on Elastic Beanstalk and make it run "print_helloworld.py" periodically after deployment.

But, the flask app gets error during deployment:

```
2021/11/11 19:56:13.160939 [INFO] Executing instruction: RunAppDeployPostDeployHooks
2021/11/11 19:56:13.160959 [INFO] Executing platform hooks in .platform/hooks/postdeploy/
2021/11/11 19:56:13.161018 [INFO] Following platform hooks will be executed in order: [01_runsomething.sh]
2021/11/11 19:56:13.161027 [INFO] Running platform hook: .platform/hooks/postdeploy/01_runsomething.sh
2021/11/11 19:56:13.162276 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [RunAppDeployPostDeployHooks]. Stop running the command. Error: Command .platform/hooks/postdeploy/01_runsomething.sh failed with error fork/exec .platform/hooks/postdeploy/01_runsomething.sh: permission denied
```

---

**What can I do to solve this permission error?**

I made 01_runsomething.sh executable by using Ubuntu (downloaded from Microsoft Store) on Windows 10 and used:

```
 chmod +x .platform/hooks/postdeploy/01_runsomething.sh   
 git update-index .platform/hooks/postdeploy/01_runsomething.sh
```

Then, I checked the permission on Ubuntu (ls -l .platform/hooks/postdeploy/01_runsomething.sh), and it looks like this:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 279 Nov 10 20:33 .platform/hooks/postdeploy/01_runsomething.sh
```

But, the flask app still returns same error on Elastic Beanstalk. Not sure if that solution works.

---

**What can I do to solve this permission error?**

Comment: Can you change the content of 01_runsomething.sh to #!/bin/sh echo "TEST" and try again?

Comment: @Peter Hi. Thank you. Unfortunately that didn't work. It still returns same error.

Comment: My other tip is the owner of the file is different from the user who is running the hooks. Try to write a file somewhere `/tmp` and check the permissions of that file, who is the owner etc, so finally you will see where's the permission issue coming from.

Comment: I believe this is the command you have to use - `git update-index --chmod=+x path/to/file`. Git will mark the file as changed and you have to commit it.